# Pandas: Inserting rows based on conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, insert

Imagine a below dataset.
**INPUT DATASET**

```
id      status   type  location     bb_count      vo_count   tv_count
123     open      r     hongkong       1             0          4      
456     open      r     hongkong       1             7          2
456     closed    p     India          0             6          1
```

**OUTPUT DATASET**
I need to insert a row with product type if any(bb_count, tv_count, vo_count) is greater than 0.

```
id      status   type  location        product      
123     open      r     hongkong       bb            
123     open      r     hongkong       tv          
456     open      r     hongkong       bb             
456     open      r     hongkong       vo          
456     open      r     hongkong       tv             
456     closed    p     India          vo            
456     closed    p     India          rv
```

what I tried:

```
def insert_row(df):
    if df["bb_count"] > 0:
        print("inserting bb row")
    if df["tv_count"] > 0:
        print("inserting tv row")
    if df["vo_count"] > 0:
        print("inserting vo row")

df.apply(insert_row, axis=1)
```

But I'm not getting the exact output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't changing your dataframe in the function at all. You are simply printing some statements. You don't really need a custom function for what you want to do.

Try:

1. [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe to create the required structure.
2. Filter to keep rows where the value is greater than 0.
3. Re-format the "product" column as required (removing the "_count").

```
melted = df.melt(["id", "status", "type", "location"],
                 ["bb_count","vo_count","tv_count"],
                 var_name="product")
output = melted[melted["value"].gt(0)].drop("value",axis=1)
output["product"] = output["product"].str.replace("_count","")
                                         .replace({"bb": "broadband",
                                                   "vo":"fixedvoice",
                                                   "tv":"television"})

>>> output
    id  status type  location     product
0  123    open    r  hongkong   broadband
1  456    open    r  hongkong   broadband
4  456    open    r  hongkong  fixedvoice
5  456  closed    p     India  fixedvoice
6  123    open    r  hongkong  television
7  456    open    r  hongkong  television
8  456  closed    p     India  television
```

Comment: My original solution with `melt`: `df.melt(["id", "status", "type", "location"], var_name="product").query('value > 0').drop(columns='value').assign(product=lambda x: x['product'].str.strip('_count'))` :) +1

Comment: I used `strip` in my previous edit but that removes the "t" from "tv" and "o" from "vo". Hence the `replace` :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot +1!!!

Comment: `df.melt(["id", "status", "type", "location"], var_name="product").query('value > 0').drop(columns='value').assign(product=lambda x: x['product'].str.split('_').str[0])` (bad copy/paste)

Comment: Ah - nice one-liner! I like your current solution also (just saw it) +1 back at you :D

Comment: Thanks much!! @not_speshal But if I want to replace with come other value means                  for example: instead of bb - broadband, vo - fixedvoice, tv - television

Comment: @Mahilan - Edited to include that ! :)

Comment: @not_speshal  I don't want to map after this bb, vo, tv.. I want that to be in place at the time of insertion itself. Can u pls help me on this

Comment: yes but I'm handling large no of data.. So it is better to have this full product name at the time of insertion. @not_speshal

Comment: See the edit - Just mapping or replacing shouldn't slow down your code.

Answer (score 2):

Another way without melt to keep rows ordered:

```
mapping = {'bb': 'broadband', 'vo': 'fixedvoice', 'tv': 'television'}

out = (
    df.set_index(['id', 'status', 'type', 'location'])
      .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
      .rename(columns=mapping)
      .rename_axis(columns='product')
      .stack().loc[lambda x: x > 0]
      .index.to_frame(index=False)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    id  status type  location     product
0  123    open    r  hongkong   broadband
1  123    open    r  hongkong  television
2  456    open    r  hongkong   broadband
3  456    open    r  hongkong  fixedvoice
4  456    open    r  hongkong  television
5  456  closed    p     India  fixedvoice
6  456  closed    p     India  television
```

Step-by-step:

```
>>> out = df.set_index(['id', 'status', 'type', 'location'])
                          bb_count  vo_count  tv_count
id  status type location                              
123 open   r    hongkong         1         0         4
456 open   r    hongkong         1         7         2
    closed p    India            0         6         1

>>> out = out.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
                          bb  vo  tv
id  status type location            
123 open   r    hongkong   1   0   4
456 open   r    hongkong   1   7   2
    closed p    India      0   6   1

>>> out = out.rename(columns=mapping)
                          broadband  fixedvoice  television
id  status type location                                   
123 open   r    hongkong          1           0           4
456 open   r    hongkong          1           7           2
    closed p    India             0           6           1

>>> out = out.rename_axis(columns='product')
product                   broadband  fixedvoice  television
id  status type location                                   
123 open   r    hongkong          1           0           4
456 open   r    hongkong          1           7           2
    closed p    India             0           6           1

>>> out = out.stack().loc[lambda x: x > 0]
id   status  type  location  product   
123  open    r     hongkong  broadband     1
                             television    4
456  open    r     hongkong  broadband     1
                             fixedvoice    7
                             television    2
     closed  p     India     fixedvoice    6
                             television    1
dtype: int64

>>> out = out.index.to_frame(index=False)
    id  status type  location     product
0  123    open    r  hongkong   broadband
1  123    open    r  hongkong  television
2  456    open    r  hongkong   broadband
3  456    open    r  hongkong  fixedvoice
4  456    open    r  hongkong  television
5  456  closed    p     India  fixedvoice
6  456  closed    p     India  television
```

Comment: Thanks much!! But if I want to replace with come other value means for example: instead of bb - broadband, vo - fixedvoice, tv - television @Corralien

Comment: Do you want to map `{'bb': 'broadband', 'vo': 'fixedvoice', 'tv': 'television'}`?

Comment: No, I don't want mapping but I don't want short form like bb, vo...etc. I want to have the product names as above mentioned. If I want to give some other product name, what can be the approach. Can I pls help me on this.

Comment: If the name is broadband instead of bb, it doesn't matter, it should work because the only columns we used are id, status, type and location. All other columns are considered as product.

Comment: but the thing is I would have different column names like bb_count, vo_count etc but my product name will have different name not bb,vo. So in that case I should have some other names for product

Comment: Sorry!! I thought you will do one more step for mapping. will be able to do while inserting a row itself?

Comment: Check my answer. I directly rename the column before the stack which is faster than map all rows after the transformation.

Comment: you have changed the column name, but I want bb_count, vo_count,tv,_count as my columns @Corralien

Comment: My output is not what you expect? Check the step by step details

Comment: Even if my method is faster than the `melt` answer of @not_speshal, the result of both answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is you are checking the value of the entire column. Try something like:

```
def insert_row(df):
   for i in range(len(df)):
      if df["bb_count"][i] > 0:
         '''inserting bb row'''
      if df["tv_count"][i] > 0:
         '''inserting tv row'''
      if df["vo_count"][i] > 0:
         '''inserting vo row'''

      # continue with rest of function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect coding, but it works and you get the idea:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["open", "r", "Hongkong", 1, 0, 4],
        ["open", "r", "Hongkong", 1, 7, 2],
        ["closed", "p", "India", 0, 6, 1],
    ]
)

df_bb = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]].rename(columns={0:"status", 1:"type", 2:"location", 3:"count"})
df_vo = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,4]].rename(columns={0:"status", 1:"type", 2:"location", 4:"count"})
df_tv = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,5]].rename(columns={0:"status", 1:"type", 2:"location", 5:"count"})

df_bb["product"] = df_bb["count"].map(lambda x: "bb" if x > 0 else 0)
df_vo["product"] = df_vo["count"].map(lambda x: "vo" if x > 0 else 0)
df_tv["product"] = df_tv["count"].map(lambda x: "tv" if x > 0 else 0)

df_combined = pd.concat(
    [df_bb, df_vo, df_tv]
)

df_final = df_combined[df_combined["product"] != 0].iloc[:,[0,1,2,4]]
```